# How to automatically populate date in the table that defines relationship between two other table in SQL Alcehmy?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

So, I am writing a webapp in python Flask with sqlite3 database. I am using SQLAlchemy. As part of my database I have these three tables. Here, table DisasterEvent has many to many relationship with Location Table(a disaster event occur in many locations and many disaster could have happened in that particular location. Is there a way to automatically populate association table when I insert data in DisasterEvent and Location table or should I do it populate it myself? Even if you guys haven't have sql alchemy experience, I would love to hear how it is done usually?

```
class DisasterEvent(Base):
    '''Disaster Event Table'''

    __tablename__ = 'DisasterEvent'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True, autoincrement = True)
    title = Column(String(80), nullable = False)
    glide = Column(String, nullable = False)                     
    status = Column(Enum('current', 'alert', 'past'))
    description = Column(String)
    date_occured = Column(String(11), nullable = False)
    date_ended = Column(String(11))
    disaster_type = Column(String(120), nullable  = False)

    location = relationship("Location", secondary = association_table,
                        back_populates = 'disaster_event')
class Location(Base):
    '''Disaster Location Table'''

    __tablename__ = 'Location'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    country = Column(String)
    state = Column(String)
    city = Column(String)
    lat = Column(Float)
    lon = Column(Float)

    disaster_event = relationship("DisasterEvent", secondary = association_table,
                            back_populates = 'location')

#this is the association table that joins the two above tables
association_table = Table('association', Base.metadata,
    Column('event_id', Integer, ForeignKey('DisasterEvent.id')),
    Column('location_id', Integer, ForeignKey('Location.id')))
```